# How do i specify a bold version of the theme's default font?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, winforms

I'm having problems with cross theme compatibility in windows forms.  If you don't set the font for a control on a windows form, it will use the system font with correct typeface and size.  If you want to make the font **bold**, it hard codes in the rest of the system font values for the current theme you're programming with.  For instance:

```
System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label();

this->label1->AutoSize = true;
this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(9, 12);
this->label1->Name = L"lblExample";
this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(44, 13);
this->label1->TabIndex = 3;
this->label1->Text = L"Example Text";
```

If I then change the properties of this via the properties editor so that bold = true, it adds in this line:

```
this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
```

Is there a way of using the default font, but making it bold?

Further yet, is there a way of using the system font, but making the size 3 or 4 points larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the modified font initialization directly after the InitializeComponent call in your constructor.

Also, you can you one of the many, many constructors to change the size.

```
InitializeComponent();

label1->Font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(
    label1->Font->FontFamily, 
    label1->Font->SizeInPoints + 4, 
    FontStyle::Bold,
    GraphicsUnit::Point);
```

This will keep the design view from getting confused... but you also won't be able to see it in design view.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I've found the answer:

```
this->label1->Font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font(this->label1->Font, FontStyle::Bold);
```

But this now breaks the designer view :(